# Android: How to add more than one object to screen(OpenGL)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, model, cube

I'm working with a model viewer template that displays a 3D cube in the center of the screen. What I'm trying to achieve is put another, but smaller 3D cube on the screen and in a different XY position from the main. So visually, if the original cube is in the center, I would like to place the second smaller cube to the right.

So how do I add a another cube to the screen, make it smaller, and change its position? 
Note: I'm working from a basic template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign different model transformation matrix to second object.
If you are rendering with fixed pipeline, then it's as simple as calling glMulMatrix.
If you are rendering with shaders, then pass appropriate matrix as uniform to your vertex shader.

Here's some basic reading about this subject:

- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations
- http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm
- http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl5.htm
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: @Martins I'm still having problems. I'm working from the example from this website: http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to do this.

- Modify the coordinates of the vertices of the cube (probably a bad idea).
- Modify the modelview matrix with a scale operation and a translate operation, then draw your cube again (probably a better idea). You'll have to pay attention to the order of the transformations.
- Modify the camera matrix with the reverse translate and scale operations, then draw your cube again (a not so bad idea, but convoluted and slightly unintuitive).
- Modify the viewport...

I'm also guessing that you have rotations involved (so that your cube is showing its 3D goodness), so the order of the transformations is really important.

If you want to study a little bit more, you might read the OpenGL red book, available legally for free on the internet. The first chapters answer all your questions.